# How to write the <*> when writing the Applicative instance for Reader r

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm stuck with an exercise in [Haskell Book](http://haskellbook.com/), "Chapter 22. Reader". The exercise says "Implement the Applicative for Reader" and it gives the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

newtype Reader r a =
  Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

instance Applicative (Reader r) where 
  pure :: a -> Reader r a
  pure a = Reader $ ???

  (<*>) :: Reader r (a -> b) -> Reader r a -> Reader r b
  (Reader rab) <*> (Reader ra) = Reader $ \r -> ???
```

I was able to write the `pure` after also writing a `Functor` instance (I wrote the `Functor` instance, because otherwise GHC was complaining "No instance for `(Functor (Reader r)) …` arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration In the instance declaration for `‘Applicative (Reader r)’`"):

```
{-# LANGUAGE InstanceSigs #-}

newtype Reader r a =
  Reader { runReader :: r -> a }

instance Functor (Reader r) where
  fmap f (Reader x) = Reader (f . x)

instance Applicative (Reader r) where
  pure :: a -> Reader r a
  pure a = Reader $ \_ -> a

  (<*>) :: Reader r (a -> b) -> Reader r a -> Reader r b
  (Reader rab) <*> (Reader ra) = Reader $ \r -> ???
```

But I'm stuck with the `???` part.

The book gives the following hint:

> We got the definition of the apply function started for you, we’ll
>   describe what you need to do and you write the code. If you unpack the
>   type of Reader’s apply above, you get the following.
>
> ```
> <*> :: (r -> a -> b) 
>     -> (r -> a) 
>     -> (r -> b)
>
>  -- contrast this with the type of fmap
>
> fmap :: (a -> b) 
>      -> (r -> a)
>      -> (r -> b)
> ```
>
> So what’s the difference? The difference is that `apply`, unlike
>   `fmap`, also takes an argument of type `r`.
>
> Make it so.

Yes, but how to make it so? Using *typed holes*, the compiler tells me that the type of `???` must be `b`. But I still can't see how I can construct a lambda expression that takes an `r` and returns something of type `b`, given `rab` and `ra`.

Comment: Can you also provide the definition of the `Reader` data type, for those of us who are not going to buy that book?

Comment: @Rhymoid This is a little harsh. What `Reader` is is common knowledge, after all.

Comment: Sorry for the missing Reader type, I've added it to the question above.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's play type tennis. Looking at the pieces you have in scope,

```
rab :: r -> (a -> b)
ra :: r -> a
r :: r
```

and the goal type of `b`, you can see that the only way you can get a `b` out is by applying `rab` to two arguments.

```
Reader rab <*> Reader ra = Reader $ \r -> rab _ _
```

Now, the first hole has a type of `r`, and you only have one `r` in scope.

```
Reader rab <*> Reader ra = Reader $ \r -> rab r _
```

The remaining hole has a type of `a`. The only `a` you have in scope is the return value of `ra`,

```
Reader rab <*> Reader ra = Reader $ \r -> rab r (ra _)
```

and `ra`'s argument must be an `r`, for which once again you have only one choice.

```
Reader rab <*> Reader ra = Reader $ \r -> rab r (ra r)
```

Notice that `rab` and `ra` both receive `r` as an argument. All the steps in a composed `Reader` computation have access to the same environment.

Incidentally, this definition makes `<*>` equivalent to the famous [`S` combinator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SKI_combinator_calculus) (and `pure` is `K`).